# Error message when marking all inbox notifications as read is not pluralized

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox, plurals

When using the "Mark all as read" link in your inbox, and an error occurs (e.g. if your Internet connection is spotty), regardless of the number of unread notifications, you'll get this error message:

> An error occurred while updating the status of the notification. Please try again.

which isn't pluralized. (I do appreciate just getting a single message though :))

[image]

Comment: Just get rid of the "while updating status..." and leave it short and simple "An error occurred, please try again later". No need for extra details, you know what you did that caused the error anyway.

Comment: It's not really incorrect if it fell over trying to update the _first_ notification and didn't try to update any others.

Comment: Easy fix - As tempting as it is to go short, I kinda like descriptive error messages, how's `An error occurred while updating your notification statuses. Please try again.`  sound?  Any other ideas on copy?

Comment: @KyleMit way too long. And this will be wrong (and lead to another bug report) when there is a single notification to update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This'll ship to prod later today.  Thanks Glorfindel for pointing out the awkward language and Tetsujin for the copy suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

How about…

> An error occurred while updating notification status.

Then it's a singular status, rather than singular or plural notification[s]. It also means you don't need to keep track of how many or juggle the message contents accordingly.
I think the 'please try again' is implicit & doesn't really need spelling out.